# Redirect IdentityServer Ionic 5 Capacitor Android emulator

Tags: ionic-framework, android-emulator, identityserver4, angular9, ionic5

I have `Identity Server 4` working with an `Ionic 5` APP which works fine when I run the app in the browser. When I run it in Android studio with the emulator, I then have to make some changes to the configuration such as `10.0.2.2` to target the local IS.

When I connect to IS4 from the emulator I can see in the logs that the origin received in IS is `http://localhost` which makes sense since I have the APP configured in Capacitor (https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors#capacitor). My problem is that when I try to redirect back, the in app browser is trying to open the URL is `http://localhost/<something>` which does not exist.

My question is, how can I correctly perform the redirect back to the android emulator? I can debug and I correctly sign in, but somehow when IS performs the redirect to `/connect/authorize...` I then get the app stuck.

```
capacitor.config.json:

{
  "appId": "com.example.app",
  "appName": "com.example.app",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0
    }
  },
  "cordova": {},
  "allowMixedContent": true
}
```

My Auth configuration:

```
auth_config: {
        identity_client: 'mobile_app',
        identity_server: 'http://10.0.2.2:13810',
        redirect_url: 'com.example.app://auth-callback',
        end_session_redirect_url: 'com.example.app://end-session',
        scopes: 'openid profile exampleapi',
        usePkce: true
    },
    browserAuthorityUrl: 'http://localhost:13810',
```

Identity server client configuration:

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mobile_app",
                    ClientName = "Mobile APP Ionic Angular 9 Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "exampleapi" },
                    RedirectUris = new List<string> {
                        $"{mobileBaseUrl}/auth-callback",
                        $"{mobileAppBaseUrl}auth-callback",
                        $"{mobileAppOrigin}/auth-callback",
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {
                         $"{mobileBaseUrl}/end-session",
                         $"{mobileAppBaseUrl}end-session",
                         $"{mobileAppOrigin}/end-session",
                    },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> {
                        mobileBaseUrl,
                        mobileAppOrigin
                    },
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                }
```

where

```
"mobileBaseUrl": "http://localhost:8100",
  "mobileAppBaseUrl": "com.example.app://",
  "mobileAppOrigin": "http://localhost",
```

Note that works perfectly fine using the app via `ionic serve` but it fails when I run the Android app within the emulator. I'm following the example and using the `ionic-appauth` package from here: https://github.com/wi3land/ionic-appauth-capacitor-demo

UPDATE: The URL it is stuck on is when the user is authenticated and Identity server is redirecting to: `/connect/authorize/callback?redirect_uri=com.example.app%3A%2F%2Fauth-callback&client_id=mobile_app&response_type=code&state=rLv7spCgZ2&scope=openid%20profile%20exampleapi&code_challenge=9yGKbchJ7YII2tx3jHAmcnV90kYZxsYVWz-60Ge5TQQ&code_challenge_method=S256`

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes, by changing the IP of my ID provider to by my computer’s private IP (192.168.x.x) - I ended up using a real device connected to the computer as opposed to a virtual device for better testing overall and performance. Hope it helps!

Comment: if you open chrome://inspect/#devices and reload the page the redirection issue will be solved, the issue is not related to microsoft identity server configuration it's more likely related to redirections inside the android app. 
You can as well enable localhost:80 in ur appsettings in identityserver and the whole setup will works without having to use ur local ip address